# How do I attach this ball to the cursor?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cursor, attachment

I'm currently building a porfolio. I got inspired by fubiz studio. They have this really cool ball attached to their cursor. I was wondering if anyone could explain how they did this, and could give me guidlines how to build it.

Fubiz studio:
http://fubiz.studio/en/selected-projects

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor

Comment: Learn about CSS custom cursors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other people said the best form to do it through CSS is with the class `cursor` like this:

```
.class{
  cursor: url(images-folder/cursor-image.png), auto;
}
```

On the other hand, think that you have a lot of CSS classes that you can use to modify and "play" with the cursor:

```
.alias {cursor: alias;}
.all-scroll {cursor: all-scroll;}
.auto {cursor: auto;}
.cell {cursor: cell;}
.context-menu {cursor: context-menu;}
.col-resize {cursor: col-resize;}
.copy {cursor: copy;}
.crosshair {cursor: crosshair;}
.default {cursor: default;}
.e-resize {cursor: e-resize;}
.ew-resize {cursor: ew-resize;}
.grab {cursor: grab;}
.grabbing {cursor: grabbing;}
.help {cursor: help;}
.move {cursor: move;}
.n-resize {cursor: n-resize;}
.ne-resize {cursor: ne-resize;}
.nesw-resize {cursor: nesw-resize;}
.ns-resize {cursor: ns-resize;}
.nw-resize {cursor: nw-resize;}
.nwse-resize {cursor: nwse-resize;}
.no-drop {cursor: no-drop;}
.none {cursor: none;}
.not-allowed {cursor: not-allowed;}
.pointer {cursor: pointer;}
.progress {cursor: progress;}
.row-resize {cursor: row-resize;}
.s-resize {cursor: s-resize;}
.se-resize {cursor: se-resize;}
.sw-resize {cursor: sw-resize;}
.text {cursor: text;}
.url {cursor: url(myBall.cur),auto;}
.w-resize {cursor: w-resize;}
.wait {cursor: wait;}
.zoom-in {cursor: zoom-in;}
.zoom-out {cursor: zoom-out;}
```

The part of drag the background is all about working with the background image and css/js, at the end is all about mix all the web development tools.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this to your stylesheet :

`cursor: url("images/cursor.png"), pointer;`

Answer (score 0):

I thik this is what you want

```
.custom {
  cursor: url(images/my-cursor.png), auto;
}
```

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/cursor/